# Upload Multiple Images And Store each image path in different column in mysql Dtatabase

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, image

Hiii Everyone,

Here is my HTML Form.

```
 <form action="" id="uploadForm" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" >
     <h2 class="bold text-uppercase"></h2>
     <br>
    <div>
                               <div class="input-group form-group">
                                  <label for=""> Upload Your Photo </label>
                                  <br>                              
                                  <input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile">
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group form-group">
                               <label for=""> Upload Your Resume</label>
                               <br> 
                               <input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group form-group">
                               <label for=""> SSLC Mark Sheet</label>
                               <br> 
                               <input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile">
                            </div>
```

And My Ajax Code is

```
$("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
          cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data){
      alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){}           
     });
  }));
```

And my PHP Code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","spark") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
foreach ($_FILES['userImage']['name'] as $name => $value){
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'][$name])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'][$name];
$targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'][$name];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO filedetails(filepath) VALUES ('$fileTarget')";
            $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));            

?>
<img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" width="150px" height="180px" />
<?php
}}}}

?>
```

What exactly now hapening in my code is if i upload 3 images it is storing in images folder and insert filepath details in table single column name as filepath.what i want to do is i want to split each image from the array userImage so that i will store first image in column1 and second image in column2 similarly any number of images in database.Inorder to tell briefly how could i get each value from this array $_FILES['userImage']. If anyone can tell the solution it will help me alot.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a less than optimal database design. There is no need to store images in columns. They should ideally be in rows.

Comment: i want to store 6 images for single student id.like if he upload 10th marksheet 12th marksheet these all are should be in different column of same row right.

Comment: That's even worse.

Comment: can u tell me solution for this.i was new to this technology

Comment: You are right, you should store the data for a single entity in its own row, @KavyaShree. There is no need to create separate rows for same entity that will introduce data redundancy.

Comment: No..U understand in wrong way.for single row i want to store 3 image in 3 columns for same id 1.

Comment: For ex.. for id 1 .image 1 store in column1 and image 2 store in column 2 similarily it should save in single row only..so no redundancy will happen

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestions:

- If number of photos to be saved is fixed like let's say (3) photos
  per person, provide a (3) columns for photos in your table. That would be easy.
- If number of photos to be saved is not fixed, you may want to put it
  in a single column and separate them using for example a semicolon (;). The column must be flexible, set it to like `VARCHAR(100)` (THIS ONE IS NOT GOOD THOUGH)

> Example: image_file_path1;image_file_path2;image_file_path3

- When you retrieve the data (like the example above), you must slice
  each image_file_path with the semicolon to display it or put in an `<input>` field
  (whatever you like to do).

-OR-

- **You may want to normalize your table. For example you have a table for person and photos to be uploaded can be more than (1), then
  create another table for the photos. The `photo_tbl` for example will
  have the columns `id`, `person_id`, and `img_file`.**

---

In MySQL, you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX('try;try', ';')` to split a string.

> See [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

In PHP 4+, you can use `explode(";", $string)` to split a string and store them in an array variable.

> See [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

In JQuery, you can use `string.split(';');` to split a string.

> See [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Putting it in a single column is a horrible thing to suggest. Separate them out in a new table.

Comment: Ya i dont want to put it in single column. anyone please tell how should i spllit it from array

Comment: Sorry  i cant understand @rhavendc